# Socket client in C fputs

Tags: c, sockets, buffer, scanf, fputs

I have the following client code that connects to a server:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1024], server_reply[2000];

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");
    puts("Bienvenido al Chatroom, puedes empezar a escribir en la sala!");

    //keep communicating with server
    while(1)
    {

        printf("Enter message: ");
    fgets(message, 1024 ,stdin);
        //scanf("%s" , message);

        //Send some data
        if( send(sock , message , 1024 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , server_reply ,2000, 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }

    puts(server_reply);


    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I send a message through the socket, the server echoes the message back to the client. It works most of the times, but after a few messages iterations, the echo starts to fail. Here's an example of how it fails.

> Enter Message: Hi there! Server reply: Hi there!
>
> Enter Message: Where are you from? Server reply: Where are you from?
>
> Enter Message: Nice! Server Reply: Nice! are you from?
>
> Enter Message: And you ? Server Replay: And you ? you from?
>
> ---

So it seems somehow i keep garbage in the stdout buffer or something like that. I don't really know what it is. Is there anything wrong with the code or just a simple fix up to do with fputs ? (Maybe it has something to do with message and server_reply array's size).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just before `fgets(message, 1024 ,stdin);` add `memset(message, 0, 1024);`

the same should be done for server_reply:

```
memset(server_reply, 0, 2000);
if( recv(sock , server_reply ,2000, 0) < 0)
```

and for server-side too

to read more: [Null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I understood what memset tries to do, but it still won't work. Shouldn't have anything to do with the server that's why I didn't bring it up in here, but I'm running out of options :/

Comment: @FranciscoArriagadaArroyo at server side you should use memset too, just before reading from client

Comment: Still won't work, but thanks anyway, I'm gonna keep on trying, there must be something I'm not seeing here.

Comment: @FranciscoArriagadaArroyo give us code of server, its for sure problem with NULL terminator

Comment: EDIT - Now it did! Thank you very much sir! I used the read() function instead of recv(), beacause read() stores the number of bytes of the package sent by the server (in this case, the length of the string), so, with that number stored in some variable "i" I could use server_reply[i]='/0' to discard anything besides the string I want...:D THANKS A LOT FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: I hope you meant `'\0'`, not `'/0'`?

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/227203). See _[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/227203)_ to learn more. Also, you should probably upvote it, as well.